# Left outer join sum with DAX

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, powerbi

I have 2 tables:

1. Fact sales table (sales)
2. Dimensional period table (dimperiod)

[image]

I have joined them through my model on the Period column. However, when I display the sales sum I got this.

[image]

I would like to have a row where no sales were made with a sum equal to 0. As below:

[image]

I've used the following DAX but didn't work.

```
CustomSales:=CALCULATE(SUM([Sales]), NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(sales,dimperiod))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Just change the pivot table to display blanks](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot05.html#VideoNoData).

Or add 0 to your measure. Pivot tables do not display blanks by default. The first option above forces the pivot to display blanks, but you'd need to set this per pivot table. Addition implicitly coerces a blank to a numeric type.

```
SumSales:=
SUM( 'Sales'[Sales] ) + 0
```